# What is best practice for node-cron code placement?

Tags: node.js, npm, cron

When writing [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) functions, should I be putting them in my node server.js file? Or inside specific server controller files?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just putting it in the notification server controller. Appears to work fine there.